R error: Error in if (xxxx) { : argument is of length zero
I wrote two functions:
#function 1
abs.x <- function(x){
  if (x<0) {x=-x}
  x
}

#function 2
abs.x <- function(x){  
  if(x[x<0]){
     x[x<0]=-x[x<0]
  }
  x
}

function 1 is OK.
However, some problems occurred in the test of function 2.
for function 2, three types of data were used for testing, namely c(3,-3), -3, 3.
The outputs are as follows:
abs.x(c(3,-3))
[1] 3 3
abs.x(-3)
[1] 3
abs.x(3)
[1] Error in if (x[x<0]) { : argument is of length zero

I would like to know why the output of the second test is correct (for function 2), while the third test is incorrect ( [1] Error in if (x[x<0]) { : argument is of length zero ).
I have been reading up on this error on other pages but I can't seem to find a solution related to this problem.
I would greatly appreciate any insight into this error!

Because if doesn't accept empty argument. See the help page for "Control". The cond must be "A length-one logical vector that is not NA"

  ifelse(x>0, x, -x)
}


